# Rails nested form not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm guessing this is more of a fundamental issue than the form simply "not rendering", but here it goes. I'll try to keep this brief but a fair amount of context may be needed.

I'm making a custom Rolodex app and the organization gave me specific things to include. **For this specific problem I'm dealing with contact emails only.** Ideally I would have a system like Google Contact's, where you can click to add another email field and there's a dropdown to select a category (Home, Work, etc.).

In this case the categories are coming from a table called categories. Here is a link to the entity relationship diagram I made for the entire project (not just emails): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SxPH.jpg

> **To sum things up: How do I set things up to allow the entry of emails during a contact creation/edit?**

Here's my relevant code:

**models/contact.rb**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails
end
```

**models/email.rb**

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**controllers/contacts_controller.rb**

```
# GET /contacts/new
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    @email = @contact.emails.build(params[:email])
  end
```

**views/contacts/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>

    #Other contact fields here

    <% f.fields_for @email do |email| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= email.label :category_id %><br>
          <%= email.text_field :category_id %><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= email.label :email %><br>
          <%= email.text_field :email %><br/>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I also confirmed that this whole setup works "manually". I can make contacts and categories, and then properly reference them when creating a new email by manually putting in the foreign ids. The issue here is a matter of condensing this process into one form.

Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
 <% f.fields_for @email do |email| %>
```

into

```
 <%= f.fields_for @email do |email| %>
```

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe that was the issue! I think I copied it from somewhere and never bothered checking it.

Comment: Followup question, how do I reference the params when calling `Email.new()`? email_params is nil and calling contact_parameters says that `email` is unpermitted even though I included it in `params.require(:contact).permit()`

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but in general you should have something like `params.require(:contact).permit(email_attributes: [:category_id, :email])`